# Pandas - Drop rows based on row value for multiple csv files

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, glob

There are multiple csv files in which I want to delete entire rows based on some specific keywords contained in rows. If the csv files contain `x`, `p` or `z` in any row delete the entire row. It will loop through all csv files.
Sample dataset:

```
>> df
```

```
    k   y    j
0   a   NaN  x
1   p   v    z
2   m   n    9
```

Expected outcome:

```
    k   y    j
0   m   n    9
```

I tried:

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd

os.chdir(r'mypath')
allFiles = glob.glob("*.csv")
for file in allFiles:
   df = pd.read_csv(file)
   #then no idea what to do
```

Comment: Is this a multi-columns dataframe? If not, what's the name of the last column? The values that you mention can appear on any column or a specific column? Also, did you actually try something after loading the dataframe?

Comment: Yes it's multi-columns df. The values can appear on any column multiple times. Yes I have loaded df and attached it as sample df.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df = df[(df.ne("x")&df.ne("p")&df.ne("z")).all(axis=1)]
```

Comment: It works! How can I export each new csv files keeping the filename same?

Comment: `df.to_csv(file)`